# pdf to jpg conversion

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

I normally create a jpg thumbnail from PDF files this way:

`exec('convert -contrast ./xyz.pdf[0] ./xyz.jpg');`

Alternativly I can also use this variation to create the thumbnails:

`exec("/usr/bin/gs -q -dBATCH -dMaxBitmap=300000000 -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -sDEVICE=jpeg -dJPEGQ=100 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r72 -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -sOutputFile=./xyz.jpg ./xyz.pdf -c quit");`

Now most of the thumbnails are created without any problems. But there are alwasy some cases where the thumbnails aren't created at all. No matter which of the two variations I use. The PDF files seem to be "ok" (at least I can open and view them without any problems).

Is there any other way to get the thumbnails (via script) that could work?

Thanks a lot

The error message I receive is:

```
[0] => Error: /limitcheck in --run--
[1] => Operand stack:
[2] =>    --nostringval--   --dict:9/18(L)--   --nostringval--
[3] => Execution stack:
[4] =>    %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1905   1   3   %oparray_pop   1904   1   3   %oparray_pop   1888   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   1   1   --nostringval--   %for_pos_int_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %array_continue   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--
[5] => Dictionary stack:
[6] =>    --dict:1159/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:2/20(G)--   --dict:97/200(L)--   --dict:97/200(L)--   --dict:107/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:275/300(ro)(G)--   --dict:22/25(L)--   --dict:4/6(L)--   --dict:22/40(L)--   --dict:1/1(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/1(ro)(G)--
[7] => Current allocation mode is local
[8] => Last OS error: 2
```

Comment: Did you happen to check what PDF version the PDFs that didn't work were? (Just open in Acrobat and look at the preferences). Also, what OS are you running this on? If this is windows then OS error 2 is "File Not Found"

Comment: Just noticed that your command line for the GS call is to /usr/bin/gs so I am going to make an assumption that your OS is some *nix flavor. In that case OS error code 2 is file not found. I still am suspecting the error is a PDF version issue, but I will ask this anyway, are you always running the convert command with `./xyz.pdf[0]` or do you sometimes replace the 0 with a different page number (say 5 for instance). The 5 will correspond to page 6, if the PDF has less than 6 pages then this will fail with file not found errors.

Answer (score 1):

Add the -verbose flag. It will give you all sorts of extra information.
My suspicion would be the version of the PDF file that is causing your issue. ImageMagick uses Ghostscript to process PDFs. I am not sure what version of PDF Ghostscript currently supports, but most opensource tools do not handle the latest version of PDF files.

Edit:
Thought I should add this note, not sure what scripting language you are using to `exec` from or what OS you are on, but you will probably need to parse the error stream to get the information from the commands. Not sure if the verbose output is written to the error stream, but I am fairly sure the error information (invalid file format, etc) is written to the error stream.

Answer (score 1):

I posted a blog article on how to find out the PDF version used in a PDF file at http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2010/09/how-do-i-find-out-the-pdf-version-used/